# rename files with trailing date (dd.mm.yyyy) to a prefix (yyyy-mm-dd)

Tags: date, batch-file, rename

i have a lot of old files (mostly pdfs, but also some .doc or .docx) that were named according to their content with an added date.

**Bank unneeded payment 04.10.2007**

**Bank other topic 04.11.2007**

**papers nothing to add 04.10.2007**

I want to bulk rename all files in a specific folder to change the name from

**Bank unneeded payment 04.10.2007** to **2007-10-04 Bank unneeded payment**

I already have a batch file in my sendto Folder to be able to directly activate it in any folder and it is already working to iterate over all files. It even breakes the filenames into tokens and can show me those.

What I simply don't get working:

Check if the current token (%%a) is a date in dd.mm.yyyy format (without any check if it would be valid!). If it finds a date, it should create a new string (yyyy-mm-dd) and take all the other token to build a new filename and rename the current file.

Hope you can help me with this!

Current code:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem *******************************
rem this is used to get the path of the currently used folder.
(set foldername=%1)

rem this overwrites the foldername with the "%~dp1 - expands %1 to a drive letter and path only"
call set foldername=%%~dp1

rem now we have to check how many files we find in our folder
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`dir /a:-d /b "%%foldername%%\*.*"`) do set /a dirCnt+=1

rem this version works for folders without spaces (C:\scripttest) (no "")
rem for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`dir /a:-d /b %%foldername%%\*.*`) do set /a dirCnt+=1

rem when we don't find any files with the old date format in the folder, we will abort the batch
IF (%dirCnt%) EQU (0) (
  echo No files found in folder "%foldername%". Exiting.
  pause
  EXIT 1
 )

echo Found %dirCnt% files in folder "%foldername%".
rem now we start to finally do stuff!
set tmpCnt=0
set tmp2Cnt=0
rem we will go over each FILE here
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`dir /a:-d /b "%foldername%\*.*"`) do (
  set /a tmpCnt+=1
  call echo Proceed file %%tmpCnt%% from %%dirCnt%%: %%i.

  rem here we need to find IF there is a date in format dd.mm.yyyy available
  rem here we go over each PART of that file, automatically split by " " removing the ending (~n)
  for %%a in (%%~ni) do (
rem SET "var="&for /f "tokens=1 delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%%a") do set var=%%i
rem if defined var (echo %%a is NOT numeric) else (echo %%a is numeric)
    echo %%a
    )
    rem this echos only the file extension including the . = ".doc" or ".pdf"
    echo %%~xi
    rem echo %%a
  rem IF NOT, jump to next file!

  rem we copy the dd, mm and yyyy to different variables

  rem we build a new variable with yyyy-mm-dd

  rem we remove the old date format (dd.mm.yyyy) and add the new date format (yyyy-mm-dd) to the file as prefix

  rem if this worked, we add 1 to the count!
  set /a tmp2Cnt+=1
 )


rem  set "filename=%%~nf"
rem  ren "%%f" "!filename:~0,-4!%%~xf"
rem  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do ren "%%~i" "%%~ni 1.1%%~xi"


call echo process finished without errors - %%tmp2Cnt%% from %%dirCnt%% files processed, check folders for results!
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following batch :

- Iteraes all folders from start folder `X:\folder\to\start`
- looks for a pattern with at least three dots (including the extension dot)
- checks if the name without extension ends in a date and `call :ren` sub
- in the sub reorders last 10 chars to the begin.

---

```
@ECHO OFF
For /R "X:\folder\to\start" %%A in (*.*.*.*
) Do Echo:%%~nA|findstr "[0-3][0-9]\.[01][0-9]\.[12][09][0-9][0-9]$">NUL 2>&1 && Call :Ren "%%~fA"
Goto :Eof
:Ren
Set "FileName=%~n1"
Set "FDate=%FileName:~-10%"
Set "NewName=%Fdate:~-4%-%Fdate:~3,2%-%Fdate:~0,2% %FileName:~0,-10%"
If "%NewName:~-1%" Equ " " Set "NewName=%NewName:~0,-1%"
Echo Ren "%~f1" "%NewName%%~x1"
```

If the Output looks ok, remove the echoin the last line.

Sample output:

```
Ren "Q:\Test\2017-04\06\Test blah blubb 13.10.1999.txt" "1999-10-13 Test blah blubb.txt"
```

Comment: Hi!

Thanks very much! That worked like a charm! I changed it a bit so I could use it within the sendme folder, but it works really great without any change to your submitted code! All files are checked, If they have a valid date the date will be reformated and renamed.

Thanks, helped a lot! 

Also: I never would have gotten it with so few chars used!

Comment: Just edited your question title to be less wordy ;-)